# Periodicity and Burger's equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the 1-dimensional Burger's equation on a finite interval $I=(0,1)$,
$$u_t+uu_x=u_{xx}$$
with initial condition
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
and boundary conditions
$$u(0,t)=A(t) \qquad u(1,t)=B(t).$$

> **QUESTION.** Suppose that $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are periodic functions, of integer period $m$ and $n$, respectively. Is it true that the solution to the above IBVP should be periodic in time? If so, what is the period in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Apriori, there isn't any reason for this to be true. This is false in general for any nonlinear system.

Comment: Perhaps in the long range, as $t$ grows?

Comment: As t grows, the system will settle in one of the attractors (if any) of the system. But that attractor may or may not have the periodicity of the BCs. In general, if the nonlinearity or the forcing amplitutde is small in some sense, the nonlinear system may have a solution like the one you desire. However, this needs to be confirmed on a case by case basis. In the applied community, this is studied under the umbrella of nonlinear normal modes.

Comment: See this paper: Nonlinear normal modes and spectral submanifolds:
existence, uniqueness and use in model reduction , Nonlinear Dyn (2016) 86:1493–1534

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course **not**. For instance if $A=B\equiv0$ (these are periodic), then the solution decays to $0$ as $t\to+\infty$.

Instead, and this is classical in dynamical system theory, if $A$ and $B$ are periodic as in your assumption, then you might be able to prove that there exists an initial data $f$ for which the solution is periodic with the same period $p:={\rm lcm}(m,n$). And it should be unique, because the solution mapping $S(t):u(0)\mapsto u(t)$ is $L^1$-contracting. The existence relies upon two ingredients: 1) denoting $M=\max\{\|A\|_\infty,\|B\|_\infty\}$, the set of measurable functions $a$ such that $|a(x)|\le M$ a.e. is sent into itself by $S(p)$, 2) $S(p)$ is compact in the $L^1$-topology.

Comment: Thank you. You wrote "... this is classical in dynamical system theory ...", and proceeded with existence of an $f(x)$, etc. Is there a reference for this?